# How to use several different fonts in the table of contents ?

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents, book-design

I want to use different font and size for chapters and sections in the table of contents generated by toc.
How should I customize the toc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `tocloft` package, e.g.,

```
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{subfig}  % don't forget that tocloft and subfig interact (RTM)
  {\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft}}
  {\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}}
 \makeatother
```

Then define your customisations via commands like

```
\renewcommand{\cftsecpresnum}{...}
\renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{...}
```

and

```
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{...}
```

Basically it's a case of wading through `tocloft`'s extensive documentation then getting down to lots of experimenting to see what's possible (pretty much anything) and what you need to write to make it happen as you'd like.