# Conditional loading of tocloft causes errors

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

Looking for a way to customise a table of contents, I came across [this recommendation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5835/how-to-use-several-different-fonts-in-the-table-of-contents) to use `tocloft`.  As per the suggestion (and the documentation), I've put a conditional in place which tests for the presence of `subfig` and loads the package appropriately.

This Minimum [non-]Working Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\@ifpackageloaded{subfig}
    {\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft}}
    {\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Section 1}
    Hello 1
    \section{Section 2}
    Hello 2
    \section{Section 3}
\end{document}
```

Produces several errors including:

```
./tocloft.tex:3: You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.
\@->\spacefactor 
Removing the call to `\@ifpackageloaded` and explicitly specifying
```

and

```
Missing character: There is no è in font cmex10!
/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tocloft/tocloft.sty:35: You can't 
use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.
\@->\spacefactor
```

Looking around for a solution, the TeX FAQ suggests this is the result of the package using ["... an internal command without taking 'precautions'"](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-atvert).  Explicitly calling either `\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft}` or `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}` works as advertised and is how I'm currently working around the problem.  I would, however, like to implement the conditional loading as a safety precaution.

In an effort to learn more about (La)TeX internals, I'd like to know what's the root cause of this error.  Is this a problem specific to my (MacTeX 2011) installation, or can others reproduce it?  Also, what can be done to fix it in this particular incidence?  Maybe the package's [current maintainer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/179/will-robertson) could provide some insight into this.

Comment: I've edited the question you link to so that others don't fall into the same trap that you did.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is a common one. The use of `@` is restricted to style files. If you want to use it in your document preamble (or elsewhere), you need to encompass it using the

```
\makeatletter
...
\makeatother
```

pair. So, in your preamble, use

```
\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{subfig}
    {\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft}}
    {\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}}
\makeatother
```

Read the entries [@ and @ in macro names](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-atsigns) and [\spacefactor complaints](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-atvert) on the TeX FAQ, as well as the discussion [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)

Comment: After making my post, I followed the "\@ and @ in macro names" link and was just reading through it. Thanks for clarifying this.

Comment: @Wermer: You want to add a link to [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do) in your answer, and then I can delete my answer.